# What does the -s (or --full-contents) flag in Objdump do?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, objdump

I'd love to know cause googling didn't get me an answer explaining it.

Like I know it shows 'all information in a content' but what do the hexadecimal represent?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Sorry I just updated the question

Comment: Post example output of objdump with and without the flag.